# Bootstrap row doesn't fill the rest of the space on Safari if it's next to float-left element

Tags: bootstrap-4, safari, flexbox, row

Here is the code
https://jsbin.com/pabixobula/1/edit?html,output

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="float-left" style="background:red">123123</div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="order-1">23123 1231 23123 123123 123 123 23123 1231 23123 123123 123 123 23123 1231 23123 123123 123 123 23123 1231 23123 123123 123 123 23123 1231 23123 123123 123 123</div>
        <div class="order-2">23123 1231 23123 123123 123 123 23123 1231 23123 123123 123 123 23123 1231 23123 123123 123 123 23123 1231 23123 123123 123 123 23123 1231 23123 123123 123 123</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I need to use `row` to get `order-*` class to work on the order.
It works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari 13 on Mac.

The first block is `float-left` but the `row` takes the new line on Safari.
I see the trouble may come from `display:flex`, it doesn't work properly on Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the workaround way is to add `m-0` around `row`, maybe this is the error of Safari to add extra margin on row, that creates new line.

`<div class="row m-0"></div>`